# JavaScript object has different value in source page than in console

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf, javascript-objects

So my application is wrote in java and Spring and I need to pass a hash map with **[data,value]** from backend to frontend , using THYMELEAF, so I can render them into a graph. These are my lines in my controller

```
model.addAttribute("hashValues",resultHash.values());
model.addAttribute("hashTime",resultHash.keySet());
```

When trying to access them in javascript, the **hashValues** seem to be right, but the time list has a problem. When using console.log to print **hashTime** my console says something like [1996,1997,1997] when in reality my dates are [2021-10-15, 2021-10-14, 2021-10-13]. I will add some images for a better understanding.

This is how I get the lists from the model.

```
 var time = [[${hashTime}]]
 var values = [[${hashValues}]]
 console.log(time)
 console.log(values)
```

[image: See THIS IMAGE]

I've tried using **JSON.parse** but I have the same problem. Any help is appreciated cause I've been working with JavaScript for some time and I never encountered this type of problem before.

Comment: [2021-10-15, 2021-10-14, 2021-10-13] Is no valid date expression.  Maybe you are looking for ['2015-01-01',…

Comment: They are valid but just math equations.

Comment: `2021-10-15` without quote is arithmetic operation resulting in 1996

Comment: Haha yes right :) I have updated my comment to make it more clear

Comment: Thank you @ClausBönnhoff and ProGu for the clarification, i understand the problem now. Still, do you have any suggestion on how to pass the list giving this problem ? I've tried adding single quotes to every element of the list before sending it but javascript transforms them into '&#39'.

Comment: How do you fetch the data from JavaScript?